# get a word in a file and add the line number where that word occurs and add that number in list and add to dictionary

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function index that takes one parameter, a  file name (having a full story), and returns a dictionary where the keys are the words in the  file and the values are lists containing the line numbers unique and in ascending order) that these words appear in.

to get the unique keys, I did like this :

```
    with open(filename) as file:
    text = file.read(); 
    list1 = set(text.split())
    print(list1)
    for line_num, line in enumerate(file):
        if any([word in line for word in list1]):
            print (line_num, line)
```

Not able to get the result..

Edits : Sample data added :

```
LIET

Now, by Saint Peter's Church and Peter too,
He shall not make me there a joyful bride.
I wonder at this haste; that I must wed
Ere he, that should be husband, comes to woo.
I pray you, tell my lord and father, madam,
I will not marry yet; and, when I do, I swear,
It sh
```

Answer should be -

```
{'LIET': [1], 'Now,': [3], 'by': [3], 'Saint': [3], "Peter's": [3], 'Church': [3], 'and': [3, 7], 'Peter': [3], 'too,': [3], 'He': [4], 'shall': [4], 'not': [4, 8], 'make': [4], 'me': [4], 'there': [4], 'a': [4], 'joyful': [4], 'bride.': [4], 'I': [5, 7, 8], 'wonder': [5], 'at': [5], 'this': [5], 'haste;': [5], 'that': [5, 6], 'must': [5], 'wed': [5], 'Ere': [6], 'he,': [6], 'should': [6], 'be': [6], 'husband,': [6], 'comes': [6], 'to': [6], 'woo.': [6], 'pray': [7], 'you,': [7], 'tell': [7], 'my': [7], 'lord': [7], 'father,': [7], 'madam,': [7], 'will': [8], 'marry': [8], 'yet;': [8], 'and,': [8], 'when': [8], 'do,': [8], 'swear,': [8], 'It': [9], 'sh': [9]})
```

Comment: What was the actual output (or error) and which is the desired output? Also, it would be useful to provide sample data from your file.

Comment: not getting any output, something is wrong. sample data .He shall not make me there a joyful bride.
    I wonder at this haste; that I must wed
    Ere he, that should be husband, comes to woo.
    I pray you, tell my lord and father, madam,
    I will not marry yet;

Comment: Check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do the trick

```
def index(filename):
    word_lines = {}
    with open(filename) as file:
        for line_num, line in enumerate(file.readlines(), 1):
            for word in line.split():
                if word in word_lines.keys(): 
                    if line_num not in word_lines[word]:
                        word_lines[word].append(line_num)
                else:
                    word_lines[word] = [ line_num ]
    return word_lines

print(index('test.txt'))
```

The output for the sample will be:

```
{'Now,': [1], 'by': [1], 'Saint': [1], "Peter's": [1], 'Church': [1], 'and': [1, 5], 'Peter': [1], 'too,': [1], 'He': [2], 'shall': [2], 'not': [2, 6], 'make': [2], 'me': [2], 'there': [2], 'a': [2], 'joyful': [2], 'bride.': [2], 'I': [3, 5, 6], 'wonder': [3], 'at': [3], 'this': [3], 'haste;': [3], 'that': [3, 4], 'must': [3], 'wed': [3], 'Ere': [4], 'he,': [4], 'should': [4], 'be': [4], 'husband,': [4], 'comes': [4], 'to': [4], 'woo.': [4], 'pray': [5], 'you,': [5], 'tell': [5], 'my': [5], 'lord': [5], 'father,': [5], 'madam,': [5], 'will': [6], 'marry': [6], 'yet;': [6], 'and,': [6], 'when': [6], 'do,': [6], 'swear,': [6], 'It': [7], 'sh': [7]}
```

Comment: This answer doesn't take care of punctuations.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume the file contents are already read in a string `text`. I also remove punctuation characters

```
text = "He shall not make me there a joyful bride.\n " \
       "I wonder at this haste; that I must wed Ere he, that should be husband, comes to woo. \n" \
       "I pray you, tell my lord and father, madam, I will not marry yet;"
punctuations = '!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~'
for punctuation in punctuations:
    text = text.replace(punctuation, '')
words = list(set(text.split()))
print(words)
result_dict = {}
for line_num, line in enumerate(text.split('\n')):
    for word in words:
        if word in line:
            if word in result_dict.keys():
                result_dict[word].append(line_num)
            else:
                result_dict[word] = [line_num]

print(result_dict)
{
    'a': [0, 1, 2],
    'shall': [0],
    'bride': [0],
    'He': [0],
    'make': [0],
    'me': [0, 1],
    'not': [0, 2],
    'he': [0, 1, 2],
    'there': [0],
    'joyful': [0],
    'husband': [1],
    'and': [1, 2],
    'must': [1],
    'at': [1, 2],
    'wonder': [1],
    'to': [1],
    'I': [1, 2],
    'wed': [1],
    'this': [1],
    'Ere': [1],
    'comes': [1],
    'woo': [1],
    'that': [1],
    'haste': [1],
    'be': [1],
    'should': [1],
    'father': [2],
    'will': [2],
    'pray': [2],
    'my': [2],
    'yet': [2],
    'you': [2],
    'tell': [2],
    'lord': [2],
    'marry': [2],
    'madam': [2]
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i dont want to import string, if you can find solution without using import..that would be better

Comment: import string is to strip punctuations from your words, which I assume you want? If not I can find another way to strip punctuations?